# G++ makefile command with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt5

I'm trying to generate a .exe file with g++ compiler. I tried multiple ways without sucess.

```
1) QString program = "C:/Strawberry/c/bin/g++";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "g++ -o dialog C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp";
QProcess process;
process.start(program, arguments);
process.waitForFinished(-1);

2) QProcess::execute("g++ -o dialog2 C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp");

3) QProcess::execute("g++ C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp -o dialog2");
```

Everytime I have the same error message :

"In file included from C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp:1:0:
C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.h:4:19: fatal error: QDialog: No such file or directory
compilation terminated."

Or sometimes nothing happens.

I'm using Qt 5.7 with MinGW on windows 8.1

EDIT:
So after discussing the issue with members, I did some progress.
Best code until now is :

```
system("g++ -o dialog2 -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtGui -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtCore -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtWidgets -L C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/lib C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp");
```

But this indicats me that MinGW isn't a c++ 11 compiler and it suggests me to write "-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11" in the command-line in order to update the Compiler. After typing it in the compiler, the following error appears: "Unknow command".
I tried with Qt 5.7 and 5.8 without success. 
A solution guys ?

Comment: Are you cross compiling C and C++? If not, don't spam tags.

Comment: `error: QDialog: No such file ` means no such file `QDialog`

Comment: The compiler can't find the Qt headers. Try to make this work on the command-line first.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Even if he has C and C++ source files in the project, this is about C++. Agreed with not spamming tags. Removed the unrelated language.

Comment: @filmor I tried :QProcess::execute("g++ -o dialog2 C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.h"); And it created me a dialog.gch file.

Comment: @Edward How can I make it appear ? I mean the QDialog files (cpp, ui and h) are in the folder ED30.

Comment: I think he want crosscompile Qt source without *.pro file, and so on...

add `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets` in `*.pro` file )))
Or add path to include folder key to compiler argument string

Comment: @Edward It's already in it. Qt automaticly sets this up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code you are trying to compile `dialog.cpp` makes use of Qt (QDialog in particular).

When you run `g++ -o dialog2 C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp`, g++ fails because it cannot find where Qt header and library files are.

The minimal command line to make it work would be:

```
g++ -o dialog2 -I<PathToQtheaders> -L<PathToQtLibraries> -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp
```

You might need to add some extra libraries depending on what you code needs. Note that you cannot use Q_OBJECT macro if you just compile it like that (without calling `moc` etc.).

Tip: Look at the commands generated by `qmake` on a standard Qt project.

Extra tip: You can use `QLibraryInfo::location()` to get Qt installation paths.

Also your first example should be:

```
QString program = "C:/Strawberry/c/bin/g++";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-o" << "dialog" << "C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp";
QProcess process = "g++";
process.start(program, arguments);
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

Comment: seems his first example should be `helloworld.cpp`, compiled via `cmd.exe` by hand,  and after then by `QProcess`

Comment: Hi man, thank you for your answer. So I tried this :  QProcess::execute ("g++ -o dialog2 -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include -L C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/lib C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp"); But it still shows me this : In file included from C:/Users/SM/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp:1:0:
C:/Users/SM/Documents/ED30/dialog.h:4:19: fatal error: QDialog: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: Add `-I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtWidgets` That is where `QDialog` is. you might need to do the same for QtGui and QtCore.

Comment: @BenjaminT: This time I got this : "This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options."

Comment: @AlikA Qt 5.8 requires C++11 support which is not enabled by default the the mingw version you are using. The solution is in the message: add `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` to the command line. As I said in the answer take a look at the command executed when your build a Qt project with Qt Creator (or qmake), all the command line options you need will be there.

Comment: @BenjaminT : So I tried both commands in cmd and they both show same error message: "Unknown command-line". This is really annoying tho. I'm really lost now. I tried almost everything.

Comment: @AlikA Update your question to add the details of where you are now.

Comment: @BenjaminT : Done. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @AlikA `g++ -std=gnu++11 -o dialog2 -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtGui -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtCore -I C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/include/QtWidgets -L C:/Qt/5.8/mingw53_32/lib C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp` Is this what you tried ?

Comment: @BenjaminT: I didn't try that before. But I just used it and it opened a cmd and closed it immediatly. I checked folders and no changes were made.

Comment: @AlikA I suggest you try  the commands from a command prompt (`cmd`) before using them in your software. Anyway it is expected that the command above failed as you are missing the options to link with Qt libraries (`-L<PathToQtLibraries> -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets`).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the include directory of your Qt headers.

QProcess::execute("g++ -o dialog -I C:\QtDir C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp");

QtDir is the actual location of the Qt Headers on your system like C:\Qt\include

You may also have trouble linking. The whole command is:

QProcess::execute("g++ -o dialog -I C:\QtDir\include -L C:\Qtdir\lib -l Qt C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp")

Comment: Like this : QProcess::execute("g++ -o dialog2 C:/Documents/ED30/dialog.cpp -l"); ?

Comment: You should give some more context to your answers